# How to confirm partial line of text in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, selenium

I'm writing a test to confirm that a csv file has hit my downloads folder.  As the title of the csv file is set to include the date and time of the download, it's impractical to keep changing the name of the file in my feature.  Example filename: `fleet_123456_20140707_103015.csv`

Can I include in my ruby code, something that will just confirm that the "`fleet_123456`" is present as it's the only generic part of the name that will appear on every download?

At the moment I have:

```
Then /^I should get a download with the filename "(.*?)"$/ do |file_name|
  page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should include("filename=\"#{file_name}\"")
    end
```

I'm thinking that the `"#{file_name}\"")` needs tweeking, just not sure where.

Any help would be great, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Can I include in my ruby code, something that will just confirm that the "fleet_123456" is present as it's the only generic part of the name that will appear on every download?

Yes, you can. One way would be to replace the include matcher with a regex-based one. For example, instead of

```
page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should include("filename=\"#{file_name}\"")
```

you could write

```
page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should match(/filename="fleet_[\d_]+.csv"/)
```

, which would match "fleet_123456" followed by any combination of numbers and underscores, followed ".csv". Another possibility, if you want to be a little more specific, is

```
page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should match(/filename="fleet_123456_\d+_\d+.csv"/)
```

which matches the specific arrangement of groups of numbers separated by underscores. You can read about regular expressions in Ruby [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) and play with them [here](http://rubular.com/).